# Graph API - get Page's videos insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

how can i access exact same metrics for **page videos lifetime insights** like those on the image? 
[Facebook Page Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN5fO.png)

I know that i can check Page Insights, assuming i am accessing Graph API with page access token:

```
me?fields=fan_count,insights.metric(page_video_views).since(2017-03-10){name,period,values}&metadata=1
```

API gives me data where each item represents one day.. but i would like to get lifetime OR since some date, for example page was created at 2017-03-10 so i want to get insights since this day

My question is, is there any other way to get this data? or do i have to loop through data array and store incremented value in the end?

Comment: If there is no lifetime metric available, then that’s what you’ll have to do, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Try with "me/accounts?fields=id,name,access_token,country_page_likes,talking_about_count,new_like_count,link,username,about,website,fan_count"